# How to create an object in Ruby without using new

Tags: ruby, constructor

It's possible to create a Complex number in Ruby using

```
c = Complex.new(1,2)
```

but, it can be shortened to

```
c = Complex(1,2)
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality without having to define a function outside the class, like in the example below?

```
class Bits
  def initialize(bits)
    @bits = bits
  end
end

def Bits(list) # I would like to define this function inside the class
  Bits.new list
end

b = Bits([0,1])
```

I think Ruby should allow at least one of the proposed constructors below

```
class Bits
  def initialize(bits)
    @bits = bits
  end

  def self.Bits(list) # version 1
    new list
  end

  def Bits(list)      # version 2
    new list
  end

  def Bits.Bits(list) # version 3
    new list
  end
end
```

Comment: The code you’ve given works (except adding your own functions to the top level is a little questionable). What’s wrong with it?

Comment: I think it is better to keep the constructors inside the class. This is what most other OO languages allows.

Comment: Ah, ok I think I see. Then you can’t do this. In the case of `Complex` there is both the `Complex` class and a separate `Complex` method defined on `Kernel` (so it’s available at the top level), but they are separate things that just share the name. The best you can do is probably put their definitions in the same file.

Comment: `self.Bits` vs `Bits.Bits` -> they are almost the same. The disadvantage of `Bits.Bits` is that when you change your class's name, you have to change that code too. As for you 3 constructors, they are meant to be aliases of 1 method so why not use `alias` or `alias_method` -like construct? Something that looks like `attr_* :var`. I think it is more safe and less repetitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have this snippet:

```
def make_light_constructor(klass)
    eval("def #{klass}(*args) #{klass}.new(*args) end")
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
class Test
    make_light_constructor(Test)
    def initialize(x,y)
        print x + y
    end 
end

t = Test(5,3)
```

Yes, I know you're still defining a function outside a class - but it is only one function, and now any class you want can make use of its implementation rather than making one function per class.

Answer (score 5):

```
c = Complex(1,2)
```

is actually calling [a method on Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Complex)

Comment: Right, however can't be applied generally. Those Kernel methods are implemented internally, beyond language's scope.

Comment: @DavidUnric you can use this if you want. Just create a top level method (which ends up as a private method on `Object` which has the same effect). You can even open up `Kernel` and add a method there if you specifically want it there.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can't - the () operator cannot be overriden in Ruby ([Complex class is written in C](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Complex.html)).

You could achieve something similar using []:

```
class Bits
  def self.[](list)
    Bits.new list
  end
end
```

Which would allow something like:

```
b = Bits[[1,2]]
```

Comment: Or simply use arguments list by `def self.[](*list)` and then call with `b = Bits[1,2]`.

Comment: I think it is better to link it to something like this: https://github.com/sorah/ruby/blob/master/complex.c

Answer (score 1):

If you pack your classes into some module you can use 2 methods:

- `self.included` - called when you `include Mod`
- `self.extend` - called when you `extend Mod`

I have created **very** basic method using `self.included`.

Cons: It is hard to write. You can say it is complex; It may not contain all features.
Pros: It looks *exactly* like `Complex(2,3)` (it uses `()` instead of `[]` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24351316/2597260 answer); You create just `initialize`, `self.included` create the rest.

```
module M1
  # some random classes
  class A; end 
  class B
    def initialize list
        @list = list
    end
    attr_accessor :list
  end
  class C
    def initialize var1
        @var1 = var1
    end
    attr_accessor :var1
  end
  Answer = 42
  # called on `include module_name`
  def self.included mod
    # classes are constants (in normal cases)
    constants.each do |cons| 
      class_eval do
        # I don't like hard-coded `::M1`
        klass = ::M1.const_get cons
        if klass.class==Class 
            define_method cons do |*args, &block|
              klass.new *args, &block 
            end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

include M1


p A()

b = B([1,2,3])
p b.list

c = C 42
p c.var1

puts Answer() 
# NoMethodError: undefined method `Answer' for main:Object
# thats good, because Answer is not a class!
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it solves my problem. But, it's too much code for replacing a simple def outside the class. This has to be a part of Ruby to be useful.

Comment: @Kri-ban I guess it is called over-engineering (it does something more than you required) but you may find using something like this, or `self.included`/`self.extend` somewhere in your code. What you mean "part of Ruby" ? All above methods are part of the Ruby (I am using Ruby 1.9.3).

Comment: I just meant the Ruby definition should be extended to support my original request. Probably this is the wrong forum for this discussion.

Comment: @Kri-ban I guess you can look for Ruby's mailing list or you can check github.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hack that you could (but shouldn't) use, inspired by [this blog post](https://abhibhagat.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/ruby-parentheses-overloading/):

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, **kwargs, &blk)
    Object.const_get(sym).new(*args, **kwargs, &blk)
end
```

This simply expects any unknown method name to be the name of a class and calls `:new` on the class.

With rudimentary error handling:

```
alias sys_method_missing method_missing

def method_missing(sym, *args, **kwargs, &blk)
    cls = Object.const_get(sym) if Object.constants.include? sym
    if cls.is_a?(Class) then cls.new(*args, **kwargs, &blk)
    else sys_method_missing(sym, *args, **kwargs, &blk) end
end
```

If an unknown method name is the name of a class, this calls `:new` on the class. Otherwise, it delegates the call to the original implementation of `method_missing()`.

Usage:

```
class Foo
end

foo = Foo()
p foo
```

Result:

```
#<Foo:0x00007f8fe0877180>
```